# Gedit TitleBar right click menu?

Tags: unity, gnome-terminal, gedit

After running **`gedit`** command in terminal i see the original title bar right click menu , but when i run **`sudo gedit`** command it's only show ***Close*** on menu , although when i do the same with **nautilus** it show the full menu in the two cases . How can i fix that?

`gedit`:

[image]

`sudo gedit` :

[image]

Comment: The two titlebars for `sudo gedit` and `gedit` are fundamentally different. The sudo one encompases the "single titlebar" thing, whereas the standard users doesn't. I don't know how to change this.

Comment: the same thing with all gnome apps under permission hope someone found solution

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you start `gedit` with `pkexec` or `gksudo` instead of `sudo`? The latter is not meant for graphical applications and may result in unexpected behaviour. Also, why do you run Gedit as super-user anyway? Edit your files as a regular user and copy or move them into place when you're done.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Yes, same thing happens with `gksudo`. `pkexec` isn't meant for graphical apps, so it doesn't work at all. It doesn't matter the reason why we need to use `gedit` as root, this shouldn't happen. If I'm editing a lot of root files (`/etc/rc.local`, `/etc/fstab`, `/etc/default/grub`), I'm going to use root...

Comment: I agree that GEdit should work as super-user but at the same time I wanted to point out a different, possibly better workflow.

Comment: pkexec works fine on graphical apps... if it has been configured to do so for that app.

Comment: sorry all i was on exam for `gksudo` still the same, for`pkexec` not opning and write these lines on terminal  **`Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:6437): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: `**

Comment: @Zzzach... how can you take print screen for menus ?

Comment: @user554187 You can screenshot right-clicks using gnome-screenshot. Try `gnome-screenshot -i` or just open it in the dash. Capture the whole screen *after a delay* and right-click the menu before the delay is up. Oh, and avoid using **bold** and `code` together (**`this looks bad`**). Use just `code` or just **bold**.